# Use of comments to define index relationship to another table

Tags: mysql, php

I am building a CRUD system using PHP and MySQL for custom applications I am working on.

The question I have relates to the use of comments to define indexes from one table and return the required data from another.

See the image below:
[image]

You can see in the staffID column in the staffSkillsMatrix table has a comment of:

```
staff.staffID, staff.staffNickname
```

I use this methodology to generate the relationship of a particular index in the staffSkillsMatrix  to another table (staff), which allows me to have, for example, a drop down option from another table which I generate from the comment of a particular table to another.

Is there any issue anyone can see with regards to using this, what I would consider to be a non-standard method?

For me it seems like a really useful way to avoid foreign keys and simplify the CRUD classes I am building.

So far I have not run into any issues, however thought I would reach out to the community to get some feedback on this process and to see if there are any potential pitfalls I am likely to encounter when using this method.

*I use other CRUD (PHP & MySQL) libraries in many other projects and have run into limitations when it comes to cross database relationships. This is the reason I am exploring this method.*

Not sure if I am missing some fundamental aspect of, foreign keys, indexing and index linking multiple tables together in order to simplify the way I automatically generate my output.

*Please note, I am not asking for help to make this work, it is already working, I am just seeking thoughts on any drawbacks of using this method vs more standard approaches.*

The result of this approach can be seen below:
[image]

*I am also the sole developer of this system and therefore do not have the issue of non-standardised approaches to deal with, albeit it is a very simple concept for others to understand should they need to*

Thank you for reading!

Comment: `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` provides the same information. But it returns actual data (rather than a comment - you may easily forget or misprint the relation info).

Comment: "really useful way to avoid foreign keys" -- why would you want to avoid foreign keys?

Comment: How will you deal with multi-column indexes?

Comment: @mustaccio, this is one of the questions I am trying to get a good answer on, pros and cons. I haven't really done much with foreign keys at all previously and perhaps don't know the benefits. Maybe I am implementing a less useful and powerful approach to an issue which is already dealt with.

Comment: @RickJames can you explain what you mean please, not really following you.

Comment: @Majickal - `INDEX(lastname, firstname)`, `INDEX(site_id, datetime)`,